# UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths remove cell separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I need to add a new row under the selected row. I'm using this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
[_dataSource insertObject:newDataObject atIndex:indexPath.row + 1];

NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger currentCount = indexPath.row;
[indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentCount+1 inSection:0]];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

It adds the new row in the correct position, but it also deletes the upper cell separator of the selected row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could it be that your new cell has incorrect height?

Comment: No, because when I create the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath I always use the same height. And also the content is the same.

Comment: I asked as I had an issue once that I've changed prototype cells number and the cells were resized:) and overlapping eachother

Comment: If you're using implicit height through the interface builder, override the delegate method and specify a constant height to test.

Comment: I specify row height (it's constant) in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Another strange behavior is that when I create a second row, the first one shows all cell separators properly.

Comment: I have same problem.Do you have any solution?

Comment: @Foriger Sorry, I didn't find a solution... still waiting

Comment: Thanks @Heisenberg. Problem with me is when inserting on first row on first section using insertRowsAtIndexPaths: method, and still cannot find nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like UITableViewCell has no separator in selected state. UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone just disables highlighting, but cell is `selected` anyway. adding

```
   [tableView beginUpdates];
   // insert/delete manipulations
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
   [tableView endUpdates];
```

fixes the problem